# How to trigger click on buttons coming from loop by onclick of a single button

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 3 sections coming from loop. Also I have 3 buttons. Here I need to show only first section('one') by default and first button should be active/disabled.When I click second button second section should show only and second button should be active/disabled..so on.Till now working fine.But I have a 'down button' also,on click of that, click2 button will be trigger,again on click of 'down button' click3 button will be trigger.Here is code below

### app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div *ngFor="let data of testJson">
  <div *ngIf="data.id==button_selected">
    {{data.name}}
  </div>

</div>

<div style="margin-top:10px">
  <button *ngFor="let data of testJson"
  style="display:block"
  (click)="button_selected=data.id"
  [disabled]="button_selected==data.id"
  >
    click {{data.id}}
  </button>
</div><br>
<div><button>Down arrow</button></div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  button_selected = 1;
  testJson = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'one'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'two'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'three'
    }
  ];
  name = 'Angular';
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method in your `app.component.ts`.

```
  down() {
    if (this.button_selected < this.testJson.length) {
      this.button_selected++;
    }
  }
```

and modify your down arrow button as below.

```
<div><button (click)="down()">Down arrow</button></div>
```

This is [stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wyqzis?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Same answer as mine, plus you went the extra mile of checking if it's possible to activate the next section. Have an upvote

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this

```
<button (click)="button_selected++">Down arrow</button>
```

This will activate the next section every time this button is clicked.